# Grails multi-part form server 500 error on null object when deployed, but not on local host

Tags: grails, groovy, glassfish

In my grails project I have a multipart-form that grabs the file and assigns the filename to a variable that gets stored in the database.

When I run the app from localhost with production flag I am able to successfully submit the form, however, after I deploy the app to a glassfish server, I get a server 500 error:

```
Cannot get property 'originalFilename' on null object
```

I am thinking that maybe it has something to do with not handling multipart correctly. Anyone have this issue or can point me in the right direction to solving it?

Using Grails 2.0.4 deployed to Glassfish 3 server using Oracle db.

pertinent code from my action:

```
def uploadedFile = request.getFile('filepath')// see if there is a file to upload
        if (!uploadedFile?.empty) { // is there a file? 
            sampleInstance.filepath = "file://///FileLocation/${uploadedFile?.originalFilename}" // save the original filename

        }
```

Form on gsp:

```
<g:form action="sample" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <g:textField name="name" value="${sampleInstance?.name}"/>
 ...
 <input type="file" id="filepath" name="filepath" />
 <g:submitButton name="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
</g:form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `uploadedFile` is null, then `uploadedFile?.empty` will be null, so

```
if (!uploadedFile?.empty) { // is there a file?
```

Will do the opposite of what you are expecting

You should probably be doing

```
if ( uploadedFile && !uploadedFile.empty) { // is there a file?
```

Comment: I have taken what you wrote into account, and updated my code. However, the error happens whether or not there is a file on deployment, but works fine on local machine. I am wondering if there is something I need to do to make it work with oracle.

Comment: Changing the code as you stated prevents the 500 error, however, the underlying problem remains - `def uploadedFile = request.getFile('filepath')` always results in null. So changing the code prevents it from going into the if statement and trying to grab the `originalFilename`. I have checked in firebug and there is a file instance. Not sure why it is unable to pass through.

Comment: Well, I suppose I am the only one that has had this issue, as I cannot find any information about it. I am concerned now that I won't get an answer to my problem, or even a lead in this post. Technically, tim has answered my question, so I am going to accept it and ask another question regarding the specifics of my npe.

Comment: @Universitas Sorry about the sudden silence from my end, got loads on at work atm :-( I can't see why it would always be null from the deployed glassfish grails app...  It won't have anything to do with Oracle though, as by this point it hasn't touched the db...

Comment: No problem Tim :) I always appreciate your help. Glassfish is made by Oracle, so there has to be some difference due to the environments between Jetty and Glassfish. I am definitely perplexed.